# Unable to extract specific value from Azure Key vault Secret using az keyvault secret show command

Tags: azure-cli

I am new to AzureCLI script. I request some guidance here:

Please find the secret(masked value) from my Azure key vault.

```
{
"**attributes**": {

  "created": "2021-10-23T04:26:19+00:00",

  "enabled": true,

  "id": "https://app-kv-axderfctt.vault.azure.net/secrets/connectionstr/cbcncbc",

  "name": "connectionstr",

  "**value**": "\"{\\\"eventHubNameSpace\\\":\\\"Pji-11111111-132d-46f7-af0f-aq1234\\\",\\\"eventHubName\\\":\\\"pipeline-swswsw-fb95-4e16-8364-oiu8ikji\\\",\\\"**ConnectionString**\\\":\\\"Endpoint=sb://pji-uit8tihj-132d-46f7-af0f-89897899.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=343456-ddddd-4720-b3db-oi89087;SharedAccessKey=xxxx+xxxxxxxx=;EntityPath=pipeline-ttrgfrtyh-fb95-4e16-8364-897uy678i\\\"}\""
```

I am able to get the complete `value` but not the specific `property(ConnectionString)` using below command

```
CONNECTION_STRING=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name ${{ parameters.KeyVault }} --name ${{ parameters.SecretName}}--query 'value.ConnectionString')
                    
echo "$CONNECTION_STRING"
```

I get below error:
`ERROR: incorrect usage: [Required] --value VALUE | --file PATH`

Please advise on how to extract `ConnectionString` value excluding `EntityPath` by escaping slashes `\\\`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using jq library

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Parse WarmRepo Connection String"
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
  # Parse WarmRepo Connection String
  echo 'Parse WarmRepo Connection String'

  ```
                #Refer https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ to know about jq queries

                PipelineConnectionString=`jq -r '.ConnectionString' <<<'$(${{ parameters.StreamingPipelineName }}-EventHub-connectionString)'`
  ```